# Why is my page not displaying correctly on server while the live preview is ok?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a newbie to HTML programming and web development in general.
While starting my first website I realized that it isn't displayed correctly.
When I preview the code with the live preview feature in VS Code it works perfectly but as soon as I upload it to the server it becomes a mess.
I thought, there could be a problem reading the CSS file, but the form is displayed correctly.
Screenshots and code snippets attached.
The page: https://www.surrealsneaker.com/

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPUEp.png)
[live page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2rgb.jpg)

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function validateForm() {
    if (isEmpty(document.getElementById('data_2').value.trim())) {
      alert('NAME is required!');
      return false;
    }
    if (isEmpty(document.getElementById('data_4').value.trim())) {
      alert('EMAIL is required!');
      return false;
    }
    if (!validateEmail(document.getElementById('data_4').value.trim())) {
      alert('EMAIL must be a valid email address!');
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

function isEmpty(str) {
  return (str.length === 0 || !str.trim());
}

function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,15}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
  return isEmpty(email) || re.test(email);
} <
/script>
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

video {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.vid-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* Style the form element with a border around it */

form {
  border: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
}


/* Add some padding and a grey background color to containers */

.container {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the input elements and the submit button */

input[type="text"],
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Add margins to the checkbox */

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-top: 16px;
}


/* Style the submit button */

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #470303f8;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Construction</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/Main/media/Sneakawh.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Main/site/const-style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="/Main/site/script.json"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

  </header>

  <div class="section">
    <span class="logo1">
            <img width="140" src="/Main/media/Sneaka.png">
        </span>
    <h1 id="text">our site is currently under construction</h1>
    <div class="vid-container">
      <video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="vid-bg">
                  <source src="/Main/media/Pexels Videos 1197802.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action="//submit.form" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Subscribe to our Newsletter</h2>
        <p></p>
      </div>

      <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="data_2" name="data_2" class="form-control" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" id="data_4" name="data_4" class="form-control" required>

        <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="subscribe"> Newsletter
              </label>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
      </div>
      <div style="float:right"><a href="https://www.100forms.com" id="lnk100" title="form to email">form to email</a></div>
      <script src="https://www.100forms.com/js/FORMKEY:QZ2L7TRA96TS" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </form>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Open up the developer console and see if there are any errors. There are almost certainly some issues with CSS loading.

Comment: You have a .json file, but the content of this is not JSON, but JavaScript (with a broken closing tag!), the extension of JavaScript files is .js. I recommend for you: until you learning development use a local dev environment(e.g. Xampp) instead of a public site

Comment: It's working now. I had to rename the CSS file to style.css. Thank you!

Comment: Your 'script.js' file contains HTML tags `<script>` and `</script>`. Those should be removed.